# Why is GridSplitter not working? How to find out?

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a custom `ItemControl` that uses a `Grid` for displaying items. Every other item is a GridSplitter so the user can change the sizes of the rows. I made sure the GridSplitters are added directly to the Grid and are not in `ContentPresenters` what you can see on the Snoop screenshot below. However, they still don't work. If I move the mouse over it shows the right mouse cursor but I can't drag the splitter - it doesn't move. Can you please help how I can find out why the splitters don't move? The code below is just a demonstration of the problem, it's not the real code I'm going to use.

This is how the app looks like and the Snoop window showing the GridSlitters are directly in the Grid.
[image]

This is my custom ItemsControl. It doen't create a container when the item is a GridSplitter.

```
public class GridItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return (item is GridSplitter);
    }

    protected override bool ShouldApplyItemContainerStyle(DependencyObject container, object item)
    {
        return !(item is GridSplitter);
    }
}
```

The Xaml how it's used.

```
<local:GridItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid IsItemsHost="True" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}" />
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
                            <TextBlock Foreground="DarkGray" Text="{Binding Content}" Margin="4" />
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</local:GridItemsControl>
```

The viemodel.

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    }
}
```

And this is how I create populate the view model.

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
        private MainViewModel _viewModel = new MainViewModel();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                _viewModel.Items.Add(new GridItem
                {
                    Row = i,
                    Column = 0,
                    Content = "item" + i
                });

                var splitter = new GridSplitter
                {
                    Height = 5,
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
                    Background = Brushes.CornflowerBlue,
                    ResizeBehavior = GridResizeBehavior.PreviousAndNext,
                    ResizeDirection = GridResizeDirection.Rows
                };
                splitter.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i);
                splitter.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);

                _viewModel.Items.Add(splitter);
            }

            DataContext = _viewModel;
        }
 }

public class GridItem
{
    public object Content { get; set; }
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Column { get; set; }
}
```

Why is it not working. How to investigate it further?

Answer (score 1):

try to add this tow property to your splitter declaration ResizeBehavior and ResizeDirection.

```
var splitter = new GridSplitter
            {
                Height = 5,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
                Background = Brushes.CornflowerBlue,
                ResizeBehavior = GridResizeBehavior.PreviousAndNext,
                ResizeDirection = GridResizeDirection.Rows,
            };
```

Comment: I have added it but it hasn't changed anything unfortunately.